# Where could I download libjingle_peerconnection.jar source code

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

I'm experimenting with WebRTC from Android, so far using **libjingle** from this [repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/io/pristine/libjingle/) had made me successfully creates a native android app that broadcast a WebRTC video to my webapp rendered in browser (check my project [here](https://github.com/bromoapp/caller)), or the other way around (check my project [here](https://github.com/bromoapp/callee))

But now I want to make some changes or maybe extend some functions to enable me to render MediaStream into android default VideoView. So I look for this library's source code in their [repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/io/pristine/libjingle/) but I couldn't find it (the source jars are all empty).

Does anybody knows where to acquire it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks you are using years old libjingle repo.
Follow the official WebRTC [build instructions](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) for Android to build latest code base.
You need a Ubuntu OS to build the WebRTC jar/aar for android.

Generating gradle to build the demo app in AndroidStudio:

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory $PWD/out/Debug --target "//webrtc/examples:AppRTCMobile" --use-gradle-process-resources --split-projects
```

Generating WebRTC Framework to link in any other native App:

```
./tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py
```

This command will generate [libwebrtc.aar](https://github.com/AjayChoudary/WebRTCFramework/tree/master/Android), it will contain all the dependent(.jar/.so) files. Just import this .aar into your existing App.

> You may need to change your app code, to make compatible with latest WebRTC API's.
>   See [Demo](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+archive/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp.tar.gz) & [API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+archive/master/webrtc/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc.tar.gz) source.

Then you can play with [VideoRender](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/VideoRenderer.java) & [SurfaceViewRenderer](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer.java)

Comment: Hi, Ajay thanks for your answer :)... I tried your suggestion to build from the link you gave. My question is: how many giga storage required to built? because I'm using VM with a size of 20GB and still not enough.

Comment: This will take around 20GB after build process, better create a VM with 50GB.  See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5006. You can try my latest built framework @https://github.com/AjayChoudary/WebRTCFramework/tree/master/Android

Comment: wow thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @Ajay, Can you please jump into this issue: [Unable to Compile WebRTC Library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61318223/10413749)