# Unable to Compile WebRTC Library for Android

Tags: linux, build, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am trying to compile WebRTC Native Stack to build `libwebrtc.aar` but unfortunately unable to understand what's going wrong.

---

**System Information:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
Java-Version:   OpenJDK-8-JDK
Python-Version: Python 2.7.17
```

---

I have followed the complete steps provided in the [official WebRTC Native Development for Android](http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/). These steps have been completed without any *interruption* and every step took its time for completion. Then, I have to install all the dependency needed to build the source code.

```
./build/install-build-deps.sh
```

Before compiling the code I have also checked-out to particular git branch to go into different available WebRTC versions, to list all the branches using this git command.

```
git branch -r
```

I am sharing the latest Git Branches:

[image]

---

I have tried every git branch from `branch-heads/60` to `branch-heads/m79`, and every branch has a different issue while using the compiling commands. I have tried these two procedures to build the library such as:

---

1- Using AAR Build Tools (`./tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py`)

```
confu@ubuntu:~/webrtc_android/src$ tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py
INFO:root:Building: armeabi-v7a
ERROR at //webrtc.gni:591:7: Can't load input file.
      absl_include_config,
      ^------------------
Unable to load:
  /home/confu/webrtc_android/src/third_party/abseil-cpp/BUILD.gn
I also checked in the secondary tree for:
  /home/confu/webrtc_android/src/build/secondary/third_party/abseil-cpp/BUILD.gn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py", line 234, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py", line 230, in main
    args.build_dir, args.extra_gn_switches, args.extra_ninja_switches)
  File "tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py", line 210, in BuildAar
    extra_ninja_switches)
  File "tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py", line 166, in Build
    _RunGN(gn_args_list)
  File "tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py", line 93, in _RunGN
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '/home/confu/webrtc_android/src/third_party/depot_tools/gn.py', 'gen', '/tmp/tmp1JDmHL/armeabi-v7a', '--args=arm_version=7 use_goma=false target_cpu="arm" is_component_build=false is_debug=false rtc_include_tests=false target_os="android"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

2- Using Manual Compilation (`gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'`)

```
confu@ubuntu:~/webrtc_android/src$ gn gen out/Debug --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm64"'
ERROR at //BUILD.gn:648:20: Assignment had no effect.
      java_files = [
                   ^
You set the variable "java_files" here and it was unused before it went
out of scope.
See //BUILD.gn:647:5: whence it was called.
    junit_binary("android_junit_tests") {
    ^------------------------------------
```

---

Comment: From what i see is that you are fetching specific branches have you tried fetching the mater head?

Comment: Why not using prebuilt versions? 
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'

Comment: Actually, I am developing my own library. I have to do some changes inside Native Stack. For that reason, I have chosen the WebRTC Native Development Environment.

Answer (score 3):

Usman, Follow i followed these steps and i was able to generate a valid webrtc aar module:

```
 git checkout origin/master
 gclient revert
 gclient sync
```

And you will have your issues sorted. You are checking out a branch which is behind the origin and doesn't have all dependencies and modules over there required to build your `libwebrtc.aar`

Comment: Actually, I was working on `branch-heads`, so that was an issue. I have retried using the `origin/master` branch and then I have tried the above commands and It worked for me.

Comment: In the above commands, it was `gclient revert` instead of `gclient reset` that worked for me. So I have corrected it, with one another mistake.